# R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)(installed via homebrew) crashes with seg fault when using terrain() function

Tags: r, homebrew, raster, terrain

R installed on Platform: MacOsX: Sierra. 10.12.6

I'm running into this issue (crash/core dump) via R/RStudio (cask) installed via homebrew. Note, it could be a problem related to R itself, however, it appears more likely that the problem is related to my installation of R, than R itself, given that the function is commonly used by 'others' without a problem.

Please forgive in advance if the reporting of this "bug" is inappropriate in the context of this forum. I'm wondering if the homebrew installation is the problem?

### Installation

```
$ brew cask install r
$ brew cask install rstudio
```

### Problem

```
>setwd("/users/my-home-dir/work/GIS/R-and-QGIS/SPATIAL_ANALYSIS/")
>dem=raster("vie_dem_srtm.tif") #elevation in meters
>plot(dem, zlim=c(1000,3000)) #areas where elevation is between 1000m-3000m

>###Calculate slope

>slope=terrain(dem,opt='slope',unit='degrees') # Problem command
```

The above command results in the following:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x131965ff8, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
1: .terrain(as.double(v), as.integer(c(tr$nrows[i] + 2, nc)), rs, un, 
nopt, lonlat, y)
2: terrain(dem, opt = "slope", unit = "degrees")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection?:
```

Expected result is no segfault and a value for slope.

Comment: this is an appropriate venue, but you might have more luck at https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues/ (cross-posting isn't great: probably best either to delete this and re-post there, or wait a day or two to see if you get any nibbles and then re-post there if not)

Comment: Thanks, I'l try that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the example in `?terrain` ?

```
library(raster)
elevation <- getData('alt', country='CHE')
x <- terrain(elevation, opt='slope', unit='degrees')
```

That works for me on a Mac (High Sierra) and it also works for the CRAN Mac.

If the example works for you, then contact the maintainer of the raster package (me) via email or github as Ben Bolker suggests, and make the offending file available to see if the problem you encountered can be reproduced.

Comment: Works perfectly, implying that the problem is related to the file *I* used. Thank you both Ben and Robert. 

Still, the segfault is troubling. I could attach the file here, except I don't see how? Apologies, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: The problem is likely more general, but only revealed by that file. I do not think you can attach it. You can put it somewhere else and then provide a hyperlink.  If that is a challenge, you can at least show `show(dem)`